# Htaccess ReWrite, and Add folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I am using EasyBlog on Joomla, and the URLs are generated like below:

`http://www.eguardtech.com/blog/entry/2012/10-early-warning-signs-of-impending-computer-disasters`

The old site, had a similar structure, shown as below:

`http://www.eguardtech.com/blog/2012/10-early-warning-signs-of-impending-computer-disasters`

I want to add a Rewrite rule, that replaced /blog with /blog/entry/

This needs to also keep the alias (name of the blog, typically) after the URL.

I tried, and failed using the following:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*)$ http://www.eguardtech.com/blog/entry/$1 [R,L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Order does matter in mod_rewrite rules.** Add this rule **on top of all other rules** (even before Joomla rules):

```
RewriteRule ^blog/((?!entry/).*)$ /blog/entry/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Glad to know, please consider making this answer as accepted.